# Is there a way to create osx/ios like bundle for win32 application?

Tags: ios, windows, macos

osx/ios .app file is cool because it is actually a bundle that contains resources, executable, dll etc in a single user invisible place. In another hand, win32 application expose the internal detials to end user. Is there any way to create osx/ios bundle appliction?

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind would be using stuff such as a resource compiler. Or, usually, I tend to package all my contents in a .zip-like custom format.